# Várias tabelas lado a lado

Tags: html, css

Boa noite!

Estou aprendendo html + css, e gostaria de fazer com que as minhas 3 tabelas, fiquem lado a lado na horizontal mesmo que ultrapasse o limite direito da tela(habilitar a barra de rolagem)

É possível fazer?

Segue código abaixo:

```html
<div id="div1">
    <table id="table1" >
        <tr>
            <th class="class1">Name</th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br/>10</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br/>11</th>
            <th>Su
                <br/>12</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br/>13</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br/>14</th>
            <th>We
                <br/>15</th>
            <th>Th
                <br/>16</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br/>17</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br/>18</th>
            <th>Su
                <br/>19</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br/>20</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br/>21</th>
            <th>We
                <br/>22</th>
            <th>Th
                <br/>23</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Vestibulum consequat dapibus nibh, ac bibendum turpis ornare ut.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 <table id="table1" >
        <tr>
            <th class="class1">Name</th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br/>10</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br/>11</th>
            <th>Su
                <br/>12</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br/>13</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br/>14</th>
            <th>We
                <br/>15</th>
            <th>Th
                <br/>16</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br/>17</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br/>18</th>
            <th>Su
                <br/>19</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br/>20</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br/>21</th>
            <th>We
                <br/>22</th>
            <th>Th
                <br/>23</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Vestibulum consequat dapibus nibh, ac bibendum turpis ornare ut.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 <table id="table1" >
        <tr>
            <th class="class1">Name</th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br/>10</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br/>11</th>
            <th>Su
                <br/>12</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br/>13</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br/>14</th>
            <th>We
                <br/>15</th>
            <th>Th
                <br/>16</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br/>17</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br/>18</th>
            <th>Su
                <br/>19</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br/>20</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br/>21</th>
            <th>We
                <br/>22</th>
            <th>Th
                <br/>23</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Vestibulum consequat dapibus nibh, ac bibendum turpis ornare ut.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além de adicionar o **display flex** na **div** que você está utilizando como **container** é necessário adicionar a propriedade **flex-shrink** como **0** na tabela, para que ela não se limite ao tamanho da janela.

```css
#div1 {
    display: flex;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <th class="class1">Name</th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br />10</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br />11</th>
            <th>Su
                <br />12</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br />13</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br />14</th>
            <th>We
                <br />15</th>
            <th>Th
                <br />16</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br />17</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br />18</th>
            <th>Su
                <br />19</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br />20</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br />21</th>
            <th>We
                <br />22</th>
            <th>Th
                <br />23</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Vestibulum consequat dapibus nibh, ac bibendum turpis ornare ut.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <th class="class1">Name</th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br />10</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br />11</th>
            <th>Su
                <br />12</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br />13</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br />14</th>
            <th>We
                <br />15</th>
            <th>Th
                <br />16</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br />17</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br />18</th>
            <th>Su
                <br />19</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br />20</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br />21</th>
            <th>We
                <br />22</th>
            <th>Th
                <br />23</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Vestibulum consequat dapibus nibh, ac bibendum turpis ornare ut.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <th class="class1">Name</th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br />10</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br />11</th>
            <th>Su
                <br />12</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br />13</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br />14</th>
            <th>We
                <br />15</th>
            <th>Th
                <br />16</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br />17</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br />18</th>
            <th>Su
                <br />19</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br />20</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br />21</th>
            <th>We
                <br />22</th>
            <th>Th
                <br />23</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Vestibulum consequat dapibus nibh, ac bibendum turpis ornare ut.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No caso da tabela a situação é um pouco diferente, pois **não se deve mexer no `display` da tabela**, o que eu quero dizer é que a tag `<table>` por padrão tem `display:table` e vc não deve mudar isso de nenhuma forma! Então a solução que eu indico e mudar o `display` da `div#div1` que vc está usando como `container` para colocar as 3 tabelas dentro.

Nessa `div#div1` coloque `display:flex`, com isso as 3 tabelas vão ficar uma ao lado da outra.

```css
#div1 {
    display: flex;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <th class="class1">Name</th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br />10</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br />11</th>
            <th>Su
                <br />12</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br />13</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br />14</th>
            <th>We
                <br />15</th>
            <th>Th
                <br />16</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br />17</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br />18</th>
            <th>Su
                <br />19</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br />20</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br />21</th>
            <th>We
                <br />22</th>
            <th>Th
                <br />23</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Vestibulum consequat dapibus nibh, ac bibendum turpis ornare ut.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <th class="class1">Name</th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br />10</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br />11</th>
            <th>Su
                <br />12</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br />13</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br />14</th>
            <th>We
                <br />15</th>
            <th>Th
                <br />16</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br />17</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br />18</th>
            <th>Su
                <br />19</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br />20</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br />21</th>
            <th>We
                <br />22</th>
            <th>Th
                <br />23</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Vestibulum consequat dapibus nibh, ac bibendum turpis ornare ut.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <th class="class1">Name</th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br />10</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br />11</th>
            <th>Su
                <br />12</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br />13</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br />14</th>
            <th>We
                <br />15</th>
            <th>Th
                <br />16</th>
            <th>Fr
                <br />17</th>
            <th>Sa
                <br />18</th>
            <th>Su
                <br />19</th>
            <th>Mo
                <br />20</th>
            <th>Tu
                <br />21</th>
            <th>We
                <br />22</th>
            <th>Th
                <br />23</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="class1">Vestibulum consequat dapibus nibh, ac bibendum turpis ornare ut.</td>
            <td>Click here</td>
            <td>$100 - $300</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```